# Android - Download file from DropBox Hyperlink?

Tags: android, hyperlink, dropbox

How I can download file from dropbox's hyperlink(http://db.tt/...). There is redirection to file with https.

So how to download the file directly from share link or get direct link to the file?

Comment: if your requirement is to download only from dropbox then you could use dropbox api. `getFileStream` will fetch the required file

Comment: yes, I want only to download file from dropbox by my app, but file is not on my dropbox account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Request the db.tt URL and take a look at the `Location` header, which will tell you where the short link redirects to.
2. Replace "www.dropbox.com" in that URL with "dl.dropboxusercontent.com". (See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en.)
3. Issue a normal `GET` request to download the content.

Comment: Yes, I figured out by myself, but in the end this is not clean way to do it. Instead of this I just display dialog with WebView allow user to click "download" button.